# Issue calling a method on a parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

I am new to Python classes and trying to understand the concept of inheritance.  I have a class called `Math` which inherits from `Calc`. From `Math.product()` I am trying to invoke the base class method `mul()` as below:

```
class Calc(object):
    def mul(a, b):
        return a * b

class Math(Calc):
    def product(self, a, b):
        return super(Math, self).mul(a, b)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    m = Math()
    print "Product:", m.product(1.3, 4.6)
```

When I run the code I'm getting the error below but as far as I can tell I have only passed two args for `mul()` within `Math.product(a,b)`. Can someone shed a light as to what mistake I have made?

```
Product:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inheritance.py", line 14, in <module>
print "Product:", m.product(1.3, 4.6)
File "inheritance.py", line 9, in product
return super(Math, self).mul(a, b)
TypeError: mul() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: There is no need for any of that to be in classes, you could just `from operator import mul` and be done with it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include `self` as a parameter in

```
class Calc(object):
    def mul(a, b):
        return a * b
```

Either that or use the `staticmethod` decorator.

For example:

```
class Calc(object):
    @staticmethod
    def mul(a, b):
        return a * b
```

Right now when you call `super(Math, self).mul(a, b)` It passes in the following arguments in order, `self, a, b`. Any time you call a method on a class (dot method), it implicitly passes `self` as the first parameter.

The `staticmethod` decorator tells the function that it doesn't operate on a specific instance of the class, so there's no need to pass in `self`.

Comment: That's cool.. Both the solutions worked like a charm.. @staticmethod decorator is the most preferred way of doing that I guess, is it?

Comment: Yes, if the function doesn't use any of the properties of the class it's being called on, `staticmethod` makes it the most readable.

Comment: I like htis as answer and the OP does also: Awsome! ... but I hope the method `mul` attached to or hooked into the namespace of the class `Calc` has something more specific which has been edited away for SO, otherwise I would go with the comment of @jonrsharpe (to the question) ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant I agree. The question mentions that OP is doing this to learn about inheritance, otherwise I would've just suggested what Jon Sharpe suggested. Either that or pulling the method out of the class.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: As I wrote and meant it: The "awsome" was loud and the "but" was silent ;-) When I last time entered a new coding team, I was flooded with all the decoration that was sprinkled all over the classes and frightening the mismatch of design and `@classmethod`and `@staticmethod`often was. Enough typed, will upvote ...